# Select multiple dom elements in angular2

Tags: javascript, dom, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get multiple li's from a ul in the component template.
For one element I'm able to use ElementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('selector') but I'm having trouble if I want to target multiple elements which have a specific class.

my template:

```
  <ul class="js-side-nav-content side-nav__content">
    <li routerLink="/home">Home</li>
    <li routerLink="/create">Create</li>
    <li routerLink="/office">Office</li>
  </ul>
```

The component code:

```
sideNavContentEl: HTMLElement;
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
this.sideNavContentEl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.js-side-nav-content');
```

Here I'm selecting the `<ul>` but I would like to get the `<li>`'s.

I've tried querySelectorAll but not getting proper solution.
Is there a way to achieve this using ElementRef or do I need to take a different approach?

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` like the following should work,

```
this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.js-side-nav-content > li');
```

Comment: I've found a workaround for this current situation so I didn't need it anymore but I'm sure I'll need it in the not too distant future so I'll try it then and comment if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I dont think this works for some reason... `querySelectorAll ` does not select anything and `querySelector` selects only the first one @ChristofDecraene

Comment: Make sure you do this in ngAfterViewInit() :)